# How to display date such "x ago"

Tags: themes, date-time, date

I want display date based on how much time has passed since, i. e. *Posted 12 minutes ago*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite simple: just replace the `get_the_date()` or `the_date()` with

```
echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' ago';
```

Comment: +1 for sharing what you learned. :) Do not use this function in a theme or plugin you want to distribute internationally. Correct translation is [almost impossible](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18495). See also [ticket #9272](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9272) for more problems. And you don’t need the second parameter in your example.

Comment: Indeed, i18n in dates is a terribly issue.